# How can i search with typing in selected category only?

Tags: javascript, search

I am working on a website where i can select a category, in this case water earth or fire, and i want to search only in that selected category by the name of the picture. for example, i select the water category and the water pictures show up with their names (which works) but when i search, my search bar searches in all the categories and if 2 pictures have similar names from different categories they both show up. How can i make it search only within the selected category?

the code

```js
(function() {

  const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.btn')
  const storeImages = document.querySelectorAll('.store-items')

  buttons.forEach((button) => {
    button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      e.preventDefault()
      const filter = e.target.dataset.filter


      storeImages.forEach((item) => {
        if (filter === 'all') {
          item.style.display = 'block'
        } else {
          if (item.classList.contains(filter)) {
            item.style.display = 'block'
          } else {
            item.style.display = 'none'
          }
        }
      })
    })
  })

})();

const search = () => {
  const searchbox = document.getElementById("search-item").value.toUpperCase();

  const nature = document.querySelectorAll('.store-items');



  for (var i = 0; i < nature.length; i++) {
    let match = nature[i].getElementsByTagName('p')[0];


    if (match) {
      let textvalue = match.textContent || match.innerHTML

      if (textvalue.toUpperCase().indexOf(searchbox) > -1) {
        nature[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        nature[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }

}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <a href="#" class="btn" data-filter="all" style="background-color: #753CF8;">All</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn" data-filter="water" style="background-color: rgb(48, 117, 163)">Water</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn" data-filter="earth" style="background-color: rgb(63, 121, 25);">Earth</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn" data-filter="fire" style="background-color: maroon;">Fire</a>
</div>

<form>
  <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
  <input type="text" name="" id="search-item" placeholder="Search gallery" onkeyup="search()">
</form>

<div class="box" id="store-items">

  <div class="store-items water ">
    <img src="img/water1.jpg" class="store-img" alt="">
    <P>Ocean</P>
  </div>

  <div class="store-items earth ">
    <img src="img/earth1.jpg" class="store-img" alt="">
    <P>Bridge</P>
  </div>

  <div class="store-items fire ">
    <img src="img/fire1.jpg" class="store-img" alt="">
    <P>Flower Art</P>
  </div>
```

The first function is to filter them and the second one is the search one

Comment: Please send the code correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this (I edited script):

```js
    var filter = "all";
(function () {

        const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.btn')
        const storeImages = document.querySelectorAll('.store-items')
        buttons.forEach((button) => {
            button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
                e.preventDefault()
                filter = e.target.dataset.filter
                
                search();
            })
        })
    })();

    const search = () => {
        const searchbox = document.getElementById("search-item").value.toUpperCase();

        const nature = document.querySelectorAll('.store-items');


        for (var i = 0; i < nature.length; i++) {
            let match = nature[i].getElementsByTagName('p')[0];


            if (match) {
                let textvalue = match.innerText;

                if (textvalue.toUpperCase().indexOf(searchbox) > -1 && (nature[i].classList.contains(filter) || filter === 'all')) {
                    nature[i].style.display = "block";
                } else {
                    nature[i].style.display = "none";
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

```html
<div class="menu">
    <a href="#" class="btn" data-filter="all" style="background-color: #753CF8;">All</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn" data-filter="water" style="background-color: rgb(48, 117, 163)">Water</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn" data-filter="earth" style="background-color: rgb(63, 121, 25);">Earth</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn" data-filter="fire" style="background-color: maroon;">Fire</a>
</div>

<form>
    <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
    <input type="text" name="" id="search-item" placeholder="Search gallery" onkeyup="search()">
</form>

<div class="box" id="store-items">

    <div class="store-items water ">
        <img src="img/water1.jpg" class="store-img" alt="">
        <P>Ocean</P>
    </div>

    <div class="store-items earth ">
        <img src="img/earth1.jpg" class="store-img" alt="">
        <P>Bridge</P>
    </div>

    <div class="store-items fire ">
        <img src="img/fire1.jpg" class="store-img" alt="">
        <P>Flower Art</P>
    </div>

</div>
```

Shortly make the filter global (Becouse you need it when searching), and check the filter too in search. I called search  function from onclick listener becouse otherwise when you selected a filter, the search text would be skipped.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, ive been trying for hours now but i dont know how to do it @0x01010